# Android comunicate between library and app

Tags: android

I'm creating a library in Android and I want to pass some values (strings) from the library to the app that is using the library after some events. The app that uses the library has only one screen to display the strings sent by the library.

My app has a `MainActivity` that will populate an `listView` with the events received by the library.
It also have an `MyApp` that extends `Application`.

Here I'm doing this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

    private static MyApp sMyApp;


    public MyApp() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sMyApp= this;

        MyLibrary.getInstance().setApplication(sMyApp);

    }

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return sMyApp;
    }

}
```

In my library:

```
public class MyLibrary {
    private static MyLibrary sInstance = new MyLibrary();
    private Application mMyApp;

    public static MyLibrary getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    private MyLibrary() {
    } 

    public void setApplication(Application myApp) {
        mMyApp = myApp;

    }

    public void sendEventMessage(String message) {
        mMyApp.setEvent(message);
    }
}
```

I've tried to implement an interface in `MainActivity` so that `mMyApp.setEvent(message);` could send a message that `MainActivity` could receive but with no success.

How can I achieve what I pretend?

Comment: This code is strange all the way. Not sure what happens there, all kind of things could go wrong. Could I suggest looking into how other people implement events.

Comment: Event callbacks should be implemented by interfaces, just implement it on your class and make your library call it when needed.

Comment: @Nanoc thanks. I've tried but I have a problem. When I do setApplication I cast my application to Application. When I try to use any method I only get those from Application and I cannot cast it to MyApp. Can this be done?

Comment: You should use a interface type to do that instead of passing the application object, but still you are able to cast it to MyApp (or just make the method param be of MyApp class...) , just make sure you had imported the MyApp class in MyLibrary (but then you cant call that a library since it will only work with your application class, thats why the interface type)

Answer (score 0):

You could try callback as this sample:

Firstly, declare your callback inside library

```
public interface ILibrary {
public void onStart(String msg);

public void onProcess(String msg);

public void onFish(String msg);}

public class SDK {
private static final String START = "I'm started";

private static final String PROCESSING = "I'm running";

private static final String STOP = "I'm done";

private ILibrary mCallback;

// Make it easy for demo
public SDK(ILibrary callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
}

public void start() {
    mCallback.onStart(START);
}

public void process() {
    mCallback.onProcess(PROCESSING);
}

public void stop() {
    mCallback.onFish(STOP);
}}
```

And then do something like that:

```
SDK sdk = new SDK(new ILibrary() {

    @Override
    public void onStart(String msg) {
        Log.d("TAG", msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcess(String msg) {
        Log.d("TAG", msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFish(String msg) {
        Log.d("TAG", msg);
    }
});

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            sdk.process();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            sdk.stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            sdk.start();
        }

    };
    asyncTask.execute();
```